# Can I use a variable as the value of the option AUDIT_GUID for the CREATE SERVER AUDIT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to make the Audit_GUID value in the CREATE SERVER AUDIT command dynamic by using the NEWID() function in SQL. Below is my SQL script to do this:

```
USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @newGUID as uniqueidentifier

SET @newGUID = NEWID()

CREATE SERVER AUDIT Audit_Select_Queries    -- Name of the Audit(unique for a Server)
TO FILE 
(   FILEPATH = N'XXXX'                      -- Folder to Store Audit Files at
    ,MAXSIZE = 0 MB                         -- 0 = UNLIMITED
    ,MAX_ROLLOVER_FILES = 2147483647        -- Max possible number of Files
    ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
)
WITH
(   QUEUE_DELAY = 1000                      -- Delay Audit actions by this time for completion
    ,ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE                  -- Database operation is more important than Audit
    ,AUDIT_GUID = @newGUID                  -- UUID of the Audit (unique for a server)
)
ALTER SERVER AUDIT Audit_Select_Queries WITH (STATE = OFF)
GO
```

But I get a syntax error near @newGUID saying "Incorrect syntax near '@newGUID'"
Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

EDIT: I am working on Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

### No ...

[`CREATE SERVER AUDIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280448.aspx) is a statement – so `AUDIT_GUID` isn't a 'parameter' in the same way that a SQL Server parameter of a stored procedure is a parameter. If you're familiar with other languages, you could consider `CREATE SERVER AUDIT` as a 'special form' and, as such, you simply need to remember that it doesn't accept variables for that option.

I can understand why that's confusing as, for example, the [`BACKUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) statement(s) *do* allow variables for certain 'parameters' ("options"), namely the name of the database; e.g. this is perfectly valid T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @databaseName nvarchar = "insert_name_of_database_here";

BACKUP DATABASE databaseName
...
```

For clarifying these types of questions, just consult Microsoft's documentation for the relevant version of SQL Server if you can't remember whether some parameters or options accept variables or not. [You can easily open the relevant documentation from SSMS by highlighting the statement, built-in procedure, etc. and hitting <kbd>F1</kbd> on your keyboard.]

### But if You're Willing to Dynamically Generate the T-SQL ...

Here's how you can use dynamic SQL – via [`EXECUTE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) or [`sp_executesql`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) – to do what you're trying to do:

```
DECLARE @dynamicSql nvarchar(1000);

SELECT @dynamicSql = 'CREATE SERVER AUDIT
    ...
    AUDIT_GUID = ''' + CAST(@newGUID AS nvarchar(255)) + ''''
    + '...' + ...,

EXEC sp_executesql @dynamicSql;
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a variable name for it, maybe by using EXEC and doing the string replacement beforehand. I tried it but could not get it to work.

Comment: When writing, testing, or debugging code that generates T-SQL (or any other language!) dynamically, add liberal output of the code that you generate before executing it.